# What is the diference betwen 電気製品 and 電化製品?

Tags: word-choice

On Google Translate, both of them are 'electrical appliances'

Answer (score 19):

電化製品 is synonymous to 家電 or home/consumer electrical equipment such as cleaners, refrigerators, laundry machines, microwaves, and air conditioners.

電気製品 is less common and just means "electric products/devices" in general. Centrifuges, escalators, oscilloscopes are 電気製品, but they are usually not called 電化製品.

Answer (score 9):

Although @naruto's answer already clarifies the current distinction between the two words, it may be good to know how come those two are differentiated.

電気製品 is literally "electric product" that covers everything it should. Meanwhile, 電化製品 is literally "electri**fied** product", which is originally used to advertise a new modern lifestyle—now rather commonplace in developed countries—that replaces human power with that of electricity. Washing machine instead of washboard, vacuum instead of broom, refrigerator instead of cold closet, rice cooker instead of iron pot, etc.

So 電化製品 is a quite [path dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_dependence) name, but still preferred when you refer to home appliances.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "a path dependent word"?

Comment: @EddieKal I think I roughly meant "name that carries a historic rationale that does not always make sense today".

Comment: @EddieKal So, e.g., using 点ける for turning on an electric-light is a path-dependent word, because electric lights replaced devices in which something had to be set on fire.